# almost-‎continuous mapping

Tags: general-topology

$‎f : X ‎‎\longrightarrow Y‎‎‎‎$‎ is almost-‎continuous ‎if ‎‎$‎f‎^{-1}‎(V)‎$‎  is open (resp. closed) in ‎‎$‎X‎$‎ whenever ‎‎$‎V‎$‎ is regular open (resp. regular closed) in ‎‎$‎‎Y‎$‎.‎

‎
‎‎‎$‎f : X ‎‎\longrightarrow Y‎‎‎‎$‎ is continuous ‎if ‎‎$‎f‎^{-1}‎(V)‎$‎  is open  in ‎‎$‎X‎$‎ whenever ‎‎$‎V‎$‎ is  open  in ‎‎$‎‎Y‎$‎.‎

‎So,the  ‎continuous ‎mapping ‎is‎ almost-‎continuous. ‎‎Is the inverse correct?
Under what conditions are the two functions ‎equivalent?‎ in regular space or other space?
‎
‎

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is [semiregular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_space) then $\text{RO}(Y)$ forms a base for $Y$ so an almost-continuous $f$ is also continuous.
A regular space is semiregular.

If $X$ is the identity from $X=\Bbb R$ in the indiscrete topology to $Y=\Bbb R$ in the cofinite topology, then $f$ is almost-continuous because the only regular open subsets of $Y$ are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$, and these always have open pre-iamges. But $f$ is far from continuous because for no other open set do we have that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$.